# Saving Mats or double arrays to storage

Tags: java, opencv

I am developing a video copy detection application and i have to save video descriptors to disc.

The type of descriptor is Mat (OpenCV) or double [] (java).
So my question is what methods to choose save these descriptors:

Serialized JSON, XML, YML, ...

Database: BLOB ...

Other methods?

The number of videos descriptors is very large.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to follow the guideline and refine your question to show your effort down such  sample code attempted to solve the problem and error message if any.

Comment: Thanks i will do.